# VS2010 Macro To Change Environment Settings Based on Build Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to change my environment colors when I switch from "Debug" to "Release" configuration in Visual Studio 2010.  I want it to really stand out that I have changed a configuration.  Is there an event I can handle with a Visual Studio macro to find out when the configuration dropdown has changed?  Also, can anyone point me to the object where I change the VS environment's colors?  Thanks.